# MS graph user has multiple calendars with name 'calendar' Version #2

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

we are using software to push events to calendars using MS Graph, however 2 of the users are getting errors saying the user has multiple calendars with the name 'Calendar'

When i use the MS graph explorer on https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
I can see that there are 2 calendars setup the same, but with different ID's.

unusual thing though is that both say they are the default, both say that cannot be deleted.
I have tried to open the specific ID of one, but then when i go to make changes, it says that the object doesnt exist in the store, even though it appears when i do a "Get calendars" both appear, but then cannot patch anything.

Please help!!!

Comment: If you have the necessary permissions and can't deleted the calendar then consider you're trying to delete the default/primary calendar - which you can't delete it. Not sure if its shared calendar or group calendar. In such scenario, i would try use tool like EWSEditor or MFCMAPI to validate which is the correct folders; keep in mind that these tools are using legacy APIs and not Microsoft Graph!!

Comment: would it say though that the item doesnt exist on the store? I renamed mine and it worked, but i just cant do that on the users mailbox with the issue

Comment: (1) AFAIK you can't change the standard folder names say Calendar. See if its reflecting the same in Outlook as well after you made the call with Graph. (1) If you want to try accessing other user mailbox then you need to use client credential flow, has necessary permissions of the other mailboxes to do the changes. I am not the API call supports application permission. (3) Yes the tools will list out the list of actual folders programmatically and will let you do more advanced operations too.

Comment: Does the above helped?

Comment: Sorry about the delay, no we havent been able to resolve things yet. I can see the two calendar ID's using graph explorer but the MFC tool only see's one. Ive been in contact with our Exchange management team, and they are looking into it as its now affecting 4 users. These are all staff who have been here a while, so im querying if there there are dregs from the old MS exchange system before our OU changed. They noticed that the duplicate calendars could be archive files, so are looking into it.

Comment: Interesting insights... thanks for sharing!!